# Send Confirmation Email to New Customers does not work for Action

Tags: magento-1, email, configuration, customer-account

I set up [Confirmation Email to New Customers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-send-confirmation-email-to-new-account-subscribers) and this works if I edit a customer and change activation. but if I use the quick action from the top bar on `/admin/customer/index/` it does not work.

I select the user, at the top I set "Actions" to "Customer Activated" and "Customer Activated" to "Yes". After submit the user is active but no mail was send.

Comment: I assume you are using `Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation` if so I found this bug report. https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation/issues/18 it appears to have been solved. Have you got the most recent version installed?

Comment: @DavidManners thanks, that should be it. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension `Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation` has some really good support and continual development of features and bug fixes. It appears that the problem you are experiancing is to do with an old version of the extension. The newest version can but got via [github](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation) if not via the Magento Connect site.

The original [bug report](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation/issues/18) has now been closed with the newest version.